# "View in Browser" and "Browse with..." context menu entry on classic .asp files in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, browser, asp-classic

some bad legancy web application projects still have **classic asp** files. these project consist of 95% of classic .asp files and the rest only of asp.net (.aspx).

if you right click on an **.aspx** file in the solution explorer of VS you can choose **"view in browser" and "browse with..."**.

however if i right click on an classic **.asp** file there, there is no such option!

do you have any tip/hint/addin for me so that it will show these two context menu entries also for .asp files?

i run all my projects in IIS not the build in casini web development server VS comes with!

thanks, toebens

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VS includes the Cassini web server out which it can deliver execution of ASPX files.  However it does not include a processor for ASP pages, for that you need to run the ASP pages in IIS, hence there is no simple "Display in browser" since VS has no idea what URL to ask the browser to display.

Comment: i run all my projects in IIS not the build in casini web development server VS comes with!

Comment: @toebens:  Nevertheless the configuration in VS to run from IIS instead of Cassini still only applies to the .NET based part of the solution.  I guess heuristically VS could draw the conclusion that since IIS is specified it ought to be able to show you that menu entry on ASP pages.  However I doubt ease of ASP development is particularly high on the VS teams To-Do list ;)